# How do I optimize tens of thousands of substring searches in instance attributes in Python?

Tags: python, regex, optimization

I'm trying to write a program which autocompletes user input which may be one of the following: an airport's three letter IATA code, a city's name, a city's name in one of given languages, an airport's name, a country's name, a state's name.

The airport data is all located in instances of an `Airport` class, which has the `.match()` method, determining if any of the relevant attributes starts with the user's input.

Here's all relevant code:

```
class Location(object):
    def __init__(self, code, location_type):
        self.code = code  # Country/city/state/airport codes. Format varies.
        self.type = location_type
        self.name = self.get_name()  # String containing name of location.
        if self.type == 'city':
            self.localizations = self.get_localizations()
            # The above is a dictionary, keys are locales (ex. 'fr-FR'), values
            # are the translated city names in the specified locale.

    def match(self, pattern, match_code=False, locales=[]):
        if match_code:  # Fires if we only match for the 3 letter IATA code 
            return pattern.match(self.code)

        if not self.name:  # Some instances don't have names
            return None

        if locales and self.localizations:  # Fires if there's languages given
            for locale in locales:
                match = pattern.match(self.localizations.get(locale, ''))
                if match:
                    return locale
            return None

        return pattern.match(self.name)


class Airport(Location):
    def __init__(self, airport, city=None, state=None, country=None):
        self.code = airport
        self.type = 'airport'
        self.name = self.get_name()
        self.city = Location(city, 'city')
        self.state = Location(state, 'state')
        self.country = Location(country, 'country')

matches = []
pattern = re.compile('^' + keyword, re.I)  # Keyword is the user's input
for airport in airports:  # airports is a list of Airport instances
    if airport.match(pattern, match_code=True):
        matches.append(airport.create_match('airport', 100))
    elif (airport.city.match(pattern)
          or airport.city.match(pattern, locales=locales)):
        if airport.city.match(pattern):
            matches.append(airport.create_match('locality', 70))
        else:
            locale = airport.city.match(pattern, locales=locales)
            matches.append(airport.create_match('localised_locality', 70,
                                                locale=locale))
    elif airport.match(pattern):
        matches.append(airport.create_match('airport', 50))
    elif airport.country.match(pattern):
        matches.append(airport.create_match('country', 30))
    elif airport.state.match(pattern):
        matches.append(airport.create_match('state', 30))
```

According to my testing, the `Airport.match()` method is what takes up practically all the time. There's currently 9451 `Airport` instances, and a search takes around 50ms on my PC.

My program is what creates all these instances at startup, loading them from XML files, so I can make modifications to the source data, if necessary.

Comment: Why are you using regex, your keyword is a constant in the regex?

Comment: Also, you may want to looke into some kind of a spellchecker (trie).

Comment: I think this question belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @sln I use regex only because it seems faster to compile a pattern with `re.I` than to keep calling `str.lower()` to get case insensitive matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you’re going about this backwards.  What do I mean by that?  Well, it seems to me that your list of things to match against is static (relatively), while your user is going to be entering data one character at a time.  What you should probably do is put all of the things you might autocomplete to into a sorted array, then every time the user types another character, find the first item in the array that matches the prefix entered by the user.

You can optimise by remembering the last place you got to, so that e.g. if a user types 'S', when you get the next character you start searching at the first 'S' in your array; if they type 'SF', then you search starting at 'SF' and so on.

#### Update

Here’s an example, based on what you wrote above:

```
import bisect

# Construct the search array
search_array = [(l.code.lower(), l) for l in locations] + [(l.name.lower(), l) for l in locations] + [(a.city.lower(), a) for a in airports] + [(a.state.lower(), a) for a in airports] + [(a.country.lower(), a) for a in airports]
search_array.sort()

# Now, assume the user enters 'S'; we do
new_entry = bisect.bisect_left(search_array, ('S'.lower(), None))

if new_entry < len(search_array):
  found = search_array[new_entry]
  if found[0].startswith('S'.lower()):
    entry = new_entry
    autocompletion = found[0]

# Let's say they now enter 'F'; we do
new_entry = bisect.bisect_left(search_array, ('SF'.lower(), None), entry)

if new_entry < len(search_array):
  found = search_array[new_entry]
  if found[0].startswith('SF'.lower()):
    entry = new_entry
    autocompletion = found[0]
```

and so on.  Obviously this is just knocked together in Stack Overflow as an example.

Comment: This is something I thought about looking into. I actually have no experience with such optimizations (remembering array positions; would I essentially be working with just slices there?), but what made me stop considering that was the fact that I am dealing with numerous different lists to match against, and that in the end I'll have to fetch all relevant data anyway: I need the whole `Airport` object if any of its attributes match. Surely this wouldn't be easy to do if I were to just search through lists of strings?

Comment: @Underyx So make it a list of (string, object) tuples, e.g. `[('LHR', london_heathrow_airport_instance), ('SFO', san_francisco_airport_instance)]`.

Comment: Alright, I'll have a look. Would you mind giving me a few pointers on how to implement this? My initial idea would be to precompile a dictionary with letters as keys and a tuple of their respective starting and ending indexes in my list as values, then look up the first letter of user input in that, and search through only what I get by slicing the list at those numbers.

This can't possibly be a Pythonic solution, though.

Comment: @Underyx I’ve updated my answer slightly to give some pointers.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll be trying this out soon. I should note however that I do not have access to a user's input history, I always only have access to the latest string. Will this method still affect performance considerably well in that case?

Comment: @Underyx Even if you can’t keep track of the user’s previous entries, just using a single `bisect.bisect_left()` call will be fast.  It uses binary search, which is O(log(N)).

Comment: I just realized that I forgot to accept this answer back in March. Anyhow, I ended up using this and it's working great, Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

One solution I came up with but didn't end up using due to it being ugly and still only a tiny bit faster was the following, for reference:

When initializing the data, assign an additional attribute to each instance, called `Location.match_name`. This is just `self.name.lower()`, but by pre-assigning it, we eliminate the need to use case insensitive regex matching, and even for converting `self.name` to lowercase whenever we match against it. Instead, we compare `keyword.lower()` to `Location.match_name[:len(keyword)]`. (Not using `str.startswith()` since it has inferior performance for some reason.)

This, however, only resulted in a speedup of about 5 or 10 percent, if I recall correctly, and I decided not to sacrifice code readability and initialization time for that.

Comment: My apologies, but are you absolutely positive that this doesn't count as an answer? It does describe a way to optimize my program, which is what I was looking for in my question.

Comment: -1 Answering your own question is allowed but it is supposed to be a well-researched, highly non-trivial answer. Your answer, at least how I read it, only tells me what you have tried so far but didn't work that well. The *question* is supposed to contain this information; certainly not an answer to your own question. I suggest you add this information to your question and delete this answer.

Comment: @Ali I see where you're coming from. However, I consider this a legitimate, non-trivial (it's a mostly different approach to the problem), and even somewhat well-researched answer (I did implement and test it myself, after all.)  

As a matter of fact, it does exactly  what I wanted it to do, and I decided against using it merely since I find it ugly. Anyone else looking for an answer to a question similar to mine can find this valuable.

Comment: If you are happy with a downvoted answer, that's your decision. However, if you moved that information to the bottom of your question as an attempt to solve your problem, I would even upvote your question (-2 vs. +5). Your choice.

Comment: @Ali Your comment made my feel like I'm being bribed with votes to accept your point of view as my own. I'm sorry, but I will not concede my point that this is a legitimate solution and therefore a legitimate answer, too. The code I described here ran faster, and that's what I was looking for in my question. The drawbacks and my personal preference to prioritize readable code to this amount of gain in performance are irrelevant.

Comment: Everyone is entitled to his own opinion. I though I would leave a comment so that you know why you are being downvoted.

Comment: @Ali Had you actually used this as the answer to your question, then it would have been a legitimate answer. In fact, I have seen answers by the OP that were upvoted **because** they were actually used and were thus legitimate answers. As I understand matters here, if you do something but decide not to use it, then it should be an update to the question. I have also seen updates to questions in which the OP explains **why** he has decided not to use a particular answer.

Comment: @sabbahillel I am afraid I don't follow: *"Had you actually used this as the answer to your question, then it would have been a legitimate answer."* What question? I did not have any question here. I explained my problem with this answer.

Comment: My problem I mistyped the address I should have typed this to @Underyx. I looked at the adress on the message list and saw the one sending it to you out of the corner of my eye as I looked at the keyboard as I typed. I will recopy this to him

Comment: @Underyx Had you actually used this as the answer to your question, then it would have been a legitimate answer. In fact, I have seen answers by the OP that were upvoted because they were actually used and were thus legitimate answers. As I understand matters here, if you do something but decide not to use it, then it should be an update to the question. I have also seen updates to questions in which the OP explains why he has decided not to use a particular answer.